# is it possible to post my own facebook wall usign graph API v3.3?

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post on my own wall of facebook using API v3.3 I am getting following Error. Even after selecting all permission.

facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both manage_pages \
          and publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
          requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with \
          sufficient administrative permission

Comment: Could you paste some sample code that produces your error in this question? Without seeing your code we will have a hard time telling you what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because the token does not incl the required permissions granted. You can test this with an app in dev mode and a page token that includes manage_pages and publish_pages granted (assuming you refer to your FB Page's feed by "my own wall"), also the user needs to have admin role on that Page.

Comment: Yes, I am able to post on Page's feed, But on my profile feed is not working using the code.   

import facebook
page_access_token = "<TOKEN>"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='feed',
                  message='Test Post.')

Comment: What you mean by "profile feed"? If you refer you to your personal feed and not your page feed: you cannot publish to a user's feed via the API anymore, since the required publish_actions permission had been deprecated.